# Ubuntu 17.10 displays password on switch user

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 17.10 with xorg as display server. When I click on switch user, there is a black screen shown (for a second) where I can read my actual password (and all the passwords I have entered on logins).

Does anyone else experience this problem? Is it a known bug or is there something wrong with my setup?